# Total Not Working In Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular4-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a problem in calculating the TOTAL. Although it works BUT when i try to remove a single row, the value is still there. It is still calculated by the total. How can i fix this? When i remove a single row, only the rows that are there, is calculated for the TOTAL? Here's my stackblitz code link

[CODE LINK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2wdfz?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
 ngOnInit(){
     this.myForm.get('rows').valueChanges.subscribe(values => {
      resolvedPromise.then(() => {
        this.total = this.totals.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.total, 0);
      });
    })

  }

 onDeleteRow(rowIndex) {
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    rows.removeAt(rowIndex)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OnDeleteRow you have:
1.-Delete the totals[rowIndex]
2.-recalculate total

```
onDeleteRow(rowIndex) {
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    rows.removeAt(rowIndex);
    this.totals.splice(rowIndex,1);  //<--remove the totals[rowIndex]
    this.total=this.totals.reduce((sum,item)=>sum+item.total,0); //<--recalculate total
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yhe problem is that, the Changes depending about "i", we can add the property "material_id to totals and change the function setOnChange

```
//When we create the "totals"
//add the property "material_id" to Total
material.materials.forEach(x => {
    rows.push(this.fb.group({
    ...
    })) 
    this.totals.push({amount:0,total:0,material_id:x.id});  //<--add the property material_id
  })

//then, in the function setOnChange

    setOnChange()
    {
        const formarray=this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
        for (let i=0;i<formarray.length;i++)
        { 
          formarray.at(i).valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{
            //search the index of "material_id"
            let index=this.totals.findIndex(t=>t.material_id==val.material_id)

          if(val.dis_checkbox){
            ...
            this.totals[index].amount=value; //<--NOT this.totals[i], 
            this.totals[index].total=values;
          }
          else {
             ....
            this.totals[index].amount=value;
            this.totals[index].total=value;
         }
        });
      }
   }
```